# I killed baby Jesus - now what's the biggest religion is in modern age?

Tags: time-travel, religion

I'm a time traveler terrorist, I want back and murdered baby Jesus in his crib on the day of his birth, to his family it would seem like he just stopped breathing at the middle of the night (no one saw me doing that or traveling there, I got away unnoticed).

Now no Jesus means no Christianity & likely no Islam (being partly based on Christianity if it does survive it will be a very different then the one we know today).

Now that my time machine is charged I'm about to go back to modern age, my question is what would be the biggest religion (by population) once I get back to modern age and why?

Comment: Are you really building a world? This is one of those "build my world" for me questions. I don't think a true world builder would really ask such a question. Creating that religion is the fun part, isn't it?

Comment: You're talking about a change 2,000 years in the past. This is entirely speculative and there can't be any right answer to this, since the possible outcomes of such a change are nearly infinite. That makes the question both very broad and opinion-based.

Comment: You could travel back in time to 0 AD, clap your hands, return to the present, and possibly end up in a very different world. There's no way to predict what disturbances, even small ones, can do over a trajectory of two millenia.

Comment: If you don't kill Paul then the biggest religion will still be Christianity. He will simply write about John instead of Jesus; in those days Judaea was a very fertile ground for breeding prophets.

Comment: If you look at some current historical speculation...not a thing changes because there was no baby Jesus to kill, so your terrorist is going to be spending a great deal of time wandering around looking for a non-existent person.

Comment: It's not a good world building question, but it would have been fun to answer.  I think I would have gone with a christ-like messianic story with all the characters and followers being cockroaches.  Their primary teaching would involve not being like the humans who blew up the world because they never found a reason to just get along and work together.   I know that's giving the church a lot of probably undeserved credit, but it would have been fun to write.

Comment: Incorrect assumptions, especially "No Jesus means no Christianity." You would come back to present day, find Christianity still very much here, and then you would realize that you were one of the instruments of its story. Further, if the assumption that Christianity is correct in its teachings is accurate, then in your world the Christian bible would likely have had Jesus dying as a baby all along, and your antagonist would come to find they played into God's plan all along despite trying to hinder it.

Comment: The provocative title will only get us trolling one another.  I suggest editing the title to something like "My parallel-universe Earth has no Jesus. What is the biggest religion there?"

Comment: Monotheism seemed right, incorporating some Greek philosophy was good idea too, so was an universalistic religion. So [pick one: divine plan / historical materialism] would presumably manifest itself anyway, in not so distant way. Had it failed or split in to dozens of sects, then by default the first place would go to Hinduism or Buddhism.

Answer (score 20):

## Brianism

On 33 A.D. a man called Brian was recognized by the locals of Jerusalem as the Messiah. He said he wasn't the Messiah, but as one of his disciples attentiously noted, only the true Messiah would deny his own messianity.

He was later imprisoned on charges of terrorism and condemned to crucification. Pontius Pilate offered the people the pardon of a convict and the people chose Brian - but when the centurions arrived at the crucifixion site asking who Brian was, another convict said "me" before Brian could, so Brian ended up being crucified anyway.

His mother is quoted as having said that, according to some astrologers who visited Brian when he was a baby, he was a capricorn and thus destined to be the a king or something. Seems like he ended up being a major religious figure. Bloody lucky, those capricorns.

[A film based on his life and deeds has been produced by Monty Python.](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079470/)

Comment: Not to mention his poor command of Latin.

Comment: He wasn't the Messiah - he was a very naughty boy.

Comment: Let's forget about the 60 year old joke, this is actually a possibility. Most scholars today do acknowledge that the stories about Jesus you find in the bible are actually the collection of stories about multiple preachers that got condensed into one. This argument is often used to sort out the stories that don't fit into the modern church anymore, so take it with a grain of salt, but this is more of a legitimate answer than one would think

Comment: And with sunday morning choirs starting "Some thing in life are bad, they can really make you mad, other things just make you swear and curse..." the followers are a lot more positive and forgiving.

Comment: @Raditz_35 wrote "Most scholars today do acknowledge that the stories about Jesus you find in the bible are actually the collection of stories about multiple preachers..." I find that incredibly hard to believe that "most scholars" believe that. I would go so far as to suggest that is an extraordinary claim. Do you have any evidence, both that such an idea has been credibly suggested and backed up, and that "most scholars" believe it?

Comment: @Loduwijk there is the fact that so many characters that predate the Bible had stories similar to biblical characters. There is a whole school of thought that believes in that, called Panbabylonism. Alfred Jeremias is an author known to have drawn the parallel between Jesus (and other biblical figures) and Gilgamesh.

Comment: @Loduwijk - [Apollonius of Tyana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius_of_Tyana) is one such messisah figure contemporaneous to Jesus of Nazareth, assuming Jesus _was_ an individual figure.  Supernatural birth, stories of miracles, etc.  Not really a unique flavour, Jesus, just the one who was most successful.

Comment: @jdunlop Thank you for taking the time to respond, but the existence of other figures is not the same thing as what Raditz_35 claimed. Raditz suggestion that Jesus could have been multiple people is not even the most surprising part, but rather the claim that "**most scholars today** do acknowledge that"

Comment: @Renan see my response to jdunlop, and thank you too for the information.

Comment: @Loduwijk I could give you evidence, sadly this is the comments sections, don't expect me to. It's simply not worth the effort. It's not even your post. Other people have given you examples. They are not really what I meant, but close.